# php-express - how to find server info

Tags: php, node.js, express, server

My company system uses express framework but applied php-express on top of it
because my company is using an external service, which has nearly monopoly status in Korea.

I followed the steps in https://www.npmjs.com/package/php-express
and the php pages appear, but...

1. Server information usually available by $_SERVER[e.g. 'HTTP_HOST'] does not come up.
   (problem appears same when putting in lower case, i.e. 'http_host')
2. when I see a page that has phpinfo(), it shows strings of info not in a table format
   [image]
3. After encountering an error, I found that a php page in my system does not get parameters passed by "GET" method.

Can anyone help, please?